# 'text' is missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as you may get from the title, passing props in react is not working. And i don´t get why.

```
function Global(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveAppBar />
      <Grid sx={{ mt: 7 }}>
        {props.text}
        <HorizontalLinearStepper />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card>
        <CvContext.Provider value={value}>
          <Global text="kk" />
        </CvContext.Provider>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Because there’s no prop types that specify “text”.

Comment: "text" is an attribute not a type, and we can use any name of attribute...

Comment: You don't have any defined propTypes, but you still have the linting rule enabled that tells you that you should. One of those things is wrong.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html, https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md

Comment: thank you @jonrsharpe, I try this and it work https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-proptypes-in-react/

Comment: @mansourahmed Correct. And you don’t have a prop type for the “text” attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try destructuring the props like this:

```
function Global({text}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveAppBar />
      <Grid sx={{ mt: 7 }}>
        {text}
        <HorizontalLinearStepper />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can keep the rest the same. Destructuring props is (usually) a better practice.

Comment: This also does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you do

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


function Global(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveAppBar />
      <Grid sx={{ mt: 7 }}>
        {props.text}
        <HorizontalLinearStepper />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

Global.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string
}
```

---

But your code should work even without it, although you would be getting that warning.

Answer (score 0):

- this correction work for me

  ```
  import PropTypes from "prop-types";

  function Global(props) {
    Global.propTypes = {
      text: PropTypes.string,
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <ResponsiveAppBar />
        <Grid sx={{ mt: 7 }}>
          {props.text}
          <HorizontalLinearStepper />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Global;
  ```